# Replacing a cracked MacBook Retina Display with third-party hardware?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, repair, third-party

I need to replace a cracked Retina Display on a 15″ MacBook (2015), but I do not want to buy Apple's expensive replacement parts. Is there third-party hardware that I could use? "Retina Displays" are simply high-PPI [IPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPS_panel) or [OLED](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OLED) displays, which many other brands of laptops also use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple doesn't sell replacement parts to users, only to their authorized resellers and service centers. However, some used Apple screens are available in the aftermarket, as, for instance from [ifixit.com](http://ifixit.com).

I think your choices are:

A) Have Apple or an authorized shop replace the cracked screen;

B) Buy a used screen and install it yourself;

C) Buy a used MacBook (perhaps you could find one with broken electronics, or a bad keyboard or inoperative logic board) and take your chances that its screen will be good;

D) Find a non-authorized repair shop that can replace the screen (thus offloading the "where to get the part" challenge onto the shop, along with the risk that the "new" screen won't work); or

E) recycle your MacBook and replace it.

Comment: Thanks, Geremia. Your edits improved the clarity of the answer.

Comment: No other non-Apple display, with identical ribbon cable connectors, could be fitted in the laptop?

Comment: I think you will have a hard time attempting to fit a non-Apple screen into a MacBook Pro. That said, Apple parts are for sale online, e.g. at ifixit: https://www.ifixit.com/Store/Mac/MacBook-Pro-15-Inch-Retina-Mid-2015-Display-Assembly/IF117-049-1

Comment: Yes, but I see no screens, and the parts aren't from Apple or Apple-branded. That said, I've installed batteries from ifixit.com in several laptops and iPhones and they've worked well.

Comment: @David Check the link above. Not cheap, but it is the screen...

Comment: You're right, Scot, thanks. I had looked for "screen" and not "display." Not new, but certainly available.

Comment: I amended the Answer to include the availability of used Apple screens in the aftermarket.

Answer (score 0):

The Chinese batteries are fairly terrible. On the other hand, I replaced my girlfriend's MBP 13" 2013 retina screen with a Chinese housing (top is plastic and not aluminum). Amazingly enough the screen colour-corrected (BasiCColor) better with the Chinese IPS screen than with the Apple original. She likes to keep a clear plastic cover on the top of her MBP. Under the plastic armour, it's impossible to tell that casing is not aluminum.

Better than new for less than $150. Don't give up on your vintage MBP 13 Retina. The ones with ports are the last good portable from Apple (unless you like carrying lots of dongles).